# bootstrap date picker - how to accept date in different format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datepicker

When I pass data to the date picker using this format `$scope.eventOccurDate= new Date()`, it shows it without any problems.

But when I try a different format like this

```
$scopeeventOccurDate="2004-07-06T05:00:00.000Z"
```

and it does not work any more.

### html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="eventOccurDate" is-open="popup[0].opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close"/>
```

### javascript

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear : 'yy',
    startingDay : 1
};
$scope.format = 'yyyy/MM/dd';
$scope.eventOccurDate= new Date();
```

Comment: Please post a link to the 3rd party control that you are having problems with in your question.

Comment: bootstrap datepicker https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Check out the [format section](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format), it shows how you can have different input string from output string like using ISO 8601 date string as input but display as yyyy/MM/dd.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$scope.eventOccurDate= new Date('2004','07','06'); //2004-07-06T05:00:00.000Z
```

it will create date object

Syntax to create date object is as follows,

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])
```

**Edit** : 
It will also works

```
$scope.eventOccurDate=new Date("2004/07/06");

//Date should be in ISO format yyyy/MM/dd.
```

**Edit**:
It also works,

```
$scope.eventOccurDate=new Date("2004-07-06T05:00:00.000Z");
```

Comment: well the thing is i am getting the date from the server //2004-07-06T05:00:00.000Z, so is it possible to format it directly to date?

Comment: ok i tried this and was able to work $scope.eventOccurDate= new Date("2004-07-06T05:00:00.000Z");